# Themes in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Coming from ASP.Net web forms,  I'm trying to figure out how to do something like themes in Blazor.  Normally I would just do it all in CSS, however I have a case where we build an app and deploy two instances of it for two different parts of our organization.  In web forms we used themes and skins because there were a few places in the application where markup was slightly different.

To do something similar in blazor,  I have a "Theme" property in  my appsettings.json file.

When referring to images from within markup I do something like this, which works fine.

```
<img src="_content/themes/@AppConfig.Theme/brand/logo.svg"  />

@code {
[Inject]
public ApplicationConfiguration AppConfig {get;set;}
}
```

Appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging":
  {
    "LogLevel":
    {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationConfiguration":
  {
    "Theme": "Theme1",

    ...
  }
}
```

My plan was to do something similar with markup, where I might have two controls:

- Shared\Themes\Theme1\Control.razor
- Shared\Themes\Theme2\Control.razor

Then in my page somehow I would dynamically load the correct control based on the name of the theme, without having to write code that hardcode theme names, so I could easily just add a theme directory, and set the name.  Is that possible, or am I trying to apply too much of the webforms paradigm here?  I've looked at the DynamicControl in Blazor, but it uses the control type to specify which would me to hard code the different types.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could do it without ever asking for the Theme name. But is a really interesting topic.
I think that you could do something with inheritance, but again, you need to know the Theme name.
If you don´t want to use the Themes name in the pages, maybe you could try injecting the components. I tried this, where I decided at runtime wich component will render. Maybe applying Dependency Injection  it can be injected:

```
@page "/"

@injectableComponent

@code{
    RenderFragment injectableComponent;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        injectableComponent = __builder => {
            <ComponentTwo></ComponentTwo>
        };

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```